# How can i pass a function as a function parameter in another function?

Tags: c++, arduino

I am trying to use an Arduino library and to use one of it's functions as a parameter in my own function, but I don't know how can I do that.
I tried the code below but I get an error.

Any help will be appreciated.

P.S: I do not have an option to use `auto` keyword.

```
using namespace httpsserver;
HTTPServer Http;
typedef void (*Register)(HTTPNode*); // My typedef
Register Node = Http.registerNode;
```

When I am trying to call `Node (...)`, I get the error below.

> ```
> Cannot convert 'httpsserver::ResourceResolver::registerNode'
> from type 'void (httpsserver::ResourceResolver::)(httpsserver::HTTPNode*)' 
> to type 'Register {aka void (*)(httpsserver::HTTPNode*)}'
> ```

#### How can I create a function pointer for the type :

'`void (httpsserver::ResourceResolver::)(httpsserver::HTTPNode*)`'

I want to use it as a parameter in another function:

```
// My Declaration
void Get(void(*Register)(httpsserver::HTTPNode*), const std::string& path);

// Usage
Get (Http.registerNode(...), ""); // Like so
```

How can I do that?

Comment: In C++, there is a difference between a pointer to a function and a pointer to a memberfunction. They are incompatible, but there may be workarounds. These keywords should get you started though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A member function pointer is not a function pointer.

```
typedef void (httpsserver::*Register)(HTTPNode*); // My typedef
Register Node = &httpsserver::registerNode;
```

usage:

```
void Get(void(httpsserver::*Register)(httpsserver::HTTPNode*), const std::string& path);
Get (&httpsserver::registerNode, "");
```

you have to pass the `httpsserver::HTTPNode*` into `Register` within `Get`.

If you want to bind the arguments to the function object and call it later, you want `std::function<void()>`:

```
void Get(std::function<void()>, const std::string& path);
Get ([&]{ Http.registerNode(...); }, "");
```

note, however, that this makes lifetime of the objects refered to within the `{}` above quite dangerous.

Comment: `typedef void (httpsserver::ResourceResolver::*Register)(httpsserver::HTTPNode*);`

Worked as expected. 
Thank you very much!